# capturar combinación de teclas en Java

Tags: java

Como puedo capturar una combinación de teclas en java. tengo este código que al presionar la tecla *Ctrl* cambia el titulo de un `JFrame` a  *"ctrl"* , y al presionar la tecla *C* cambia el titulo a *"c"* , como  hago para que al presionar `ctrl + c` al mismo tiempo en el titulo aparezca `"ctrl + c"` ???

```
package clase1;

import javax.swing.*;

import com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent;

public class Clase1  extends JFrame
{

    public Clase1()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Clase1 objeto1 = new Clase1();
        objeto1.setVisible(true);
        objeto1.setSize(1244, 715);
        objeto1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        objeto1.setResizable(false);
        objeto1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initComponents() 
    {
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() 
        {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) 
            {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }

        });
    }

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL ) 
        {
            setTitle("ctrl");
        }

        if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) 
        {
            setTitle("c");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Validando el método [isControlDown](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#isControlDown())  de la clase [InputEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html) qué devolverá *true* si la tecla `CTRL` está presionada  o *false* si no lo está.

La forma de su *if* sería

```
if(evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C){
         setTitle("Control + C");
}
```

**Update**

Para poder validar dos teclas activas presionadas , una solución sería tener un *map* que almacene  el *getKeyCode* de las teclas presionadas , se añadirá el valor en el evento *keyPressed* y se eliminará en el *keyPressed* y dentro del *keyPressed* se valida que hayan teclas presionadas aún *(activas)* si el *size* del *map* es mayor a **1**.

En teoría debería ser mayor a **0** pero tener en cuenta que antes se almacena el valor por esa razón el mayor a **1** , si es así entonces verificamos que el *KeyCode*  del Up Arrow *(38)* y el valor de *C* *(67)* se encuentren en el *map* .

```
 /* Declare Map */
private Set<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<Integer>();  

addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
  @Override
  public  void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    pressed.add(e.getKeyCode());
    if (pressed.size() > 1) {
        if(pressed.contains(38) && pressed.contains(67))
            setTitle("Tecla Up + C");
      }
    }
  @Override
   public  void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
     pressed.remove(e.getKeyCode());
   }
  @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) { }

});
```

Comment: Excelente! gracias. Puedes ayudarme con algo mas? como sería el codigo si en lugar de la tecla ctrl fuera la tecla arriba??? (es decir capturar las teclas arriba y c al mismo tiempo)

Comment: no! me refiero a la tecla de direccion arriba y a la tecla c. En realidad me gustaria saber como capturar cualquier combinacion de teclas.

Comment: @Abner respuesta actualizada.

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto tu duda; sin embargo, lo he hecho creando atajos de teclado en un menu bar.
Si no me entiendes, te estoy dejando el código para que solo lo copies, ejecutes y resuelvas tu duda.

```
package Principal;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class prueba extends JFrame implements MouseListener, KeyListener, ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu mnOpciones;
    private JMenuItem mntmSalir;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    prueba frame = new prueba();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public prueba() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Accelerator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.addKeyListener(this);

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        mnOpciones = new JMenu("Opciones");
        menuBar.add(mnOpciones);

        mntmSalir = new JMenuItem("Salir");
        mntmSalir.addActionListener(this);
        //crear atajo de teclado en menu bar
        mntmSalir.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        //fin del atajo
        mnOpciones.add(mntmSalir);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == contentPane) {
            keyPressedContentPane(e);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this) {
            keyPressedThis(e);
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    protected void keyPressedThis(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        //cuando precione control
        if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL)
        {
            setTitle("control");
        }
        //cuando precione c
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C)
        {
            setTitle("c");
        }
    }
    protected void keyPressedContentPane(KeyEvent e) 
    {

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getSource() == mntmSalir) {
            actionPerformedMntmSalir(arg0);
        }
    }
    protected void actionPerformedMntmSalir(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        //cuando precione control+c
        setTitle("Control + C");
    }
}
```

Comment: por lo que sé quieres crear **cualquier tipo de atajo de teclado**, quizá mi método es muy básico, pero si lo puedes cambiar a lo que buscas verás que puedes** crear cualquier tipo de atajo de teclado**

Answer (score 0):

La mejor práctica en Swing para el manejo de teclas y combinaciones es utilizar Key Bindings.
Creas el KeyStroke con la combinación de teclas que necesites, lo registras en el InputMap del componente visual con un nombre mediante el metodo put(). Luego en el ActionMap del componente visual registras el nombre creado con un objeto del tipo Action en el que codificarás lo que desees que se haga al ser presionada la tecla o combinación de teclas.

Answer (score 0):

```
package _09_JFrame_Múltiples_Fuentes_De_Eventos_XII;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;

import javax.swing.Action;

import javax.swing.ActionMap;

import javax.swing.Icon;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import javax.swing.InputMap;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.KeyStroke;



public class MultiplesFuentesDeEvento {


    public static void main(String [] args) {


        Ventana ventana=new Ventana();

        ventana.setVisible(true);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}

class Ventana extends JFrame {

    public Ventana() {

        setTitle("Implementacion de M,F");
        setSize(500,500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);


        add(new Lamina());

    }


}

class Lamina extends JPanel {

    Lamina() {

    AccionColor accionAmarillo=new AccionColor("Amarillo",new ImageIcon("Imagenes/Iconos/15X15/Yellow.gif"),Color.YELLOW);
    AccionColor accionRojo=new AccionColor("Rojo",new ImageIcon("Imagenes/Iconos/15X15/Red.gif"),Color.RED);
    AccionColor accionAzul=new AccionColor("Azul",new ImageIcon("Imagenes/Iconos/15X15/Blue.gif"),Color.BLUE);

    add(new JButton(accionAmarillo));
    add(new JButton(accionRojo));
    add(new JButton(accionAzul));



    //getInputMap() Devuelbe un InputMap que es usado durante la Condicion
    //WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW (En este caso Accede a algo que esta dentro de la Lamina)

    InputMap MapaEntrada=getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);  //Mapa de Entrada:

    KeyStroke teclaAmarillo=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl A");   //La Combinacion de Teclas                                                                                               
    KeyStroke teclaAzul=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl B");
    KeyStroke teclaRojo=KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl R");


     MapaEntrada.put(teclaAmarillo, "fondo_Amarillo");   //Asignar la combinacion de tecla a un objeto porque no se puede asignar la combinacion de tecla directamente a la accion.
     MapaEntrada.put(teclaAzul, "fondo_Azul");
     MapaEntrada.put(teclaRojo, "fondo_Rojo");  

     //Asocia la combinacion de tecla o objeto a la accion

     //La accion que se desencadena para "ctrl A" es accionAmarillo
     ActionMap mapaAccion=getActionMap();       //getActionMap() Nos Devuelbe un objeto de tipo ActionMap utilisado para determinar que accion se decencadena para una particular combinacion de teclas 

     mapaAccion.put("fondo_Amarillo",accionAmarillo); //el metodo put() Asigna el objeto a la Accion.
     mapaAccion.put("fondo_Azul",accionAzul);
     mapaAccion.put("fondo_Rojo",accionRojo);


    }


 private class AccionColor extends AbstractAction{


    public AccionColor(String nombre,Icon icono,Color color_boton) {

        // Al pulsar un boton se construye un objeto y  con putValue() guardamos en formato clave,valor un nombre,Icono,Descripcion y un Color de Fondo.

              //   Clave      Valor
              //     |          |
        putValue(Action.NAME,nombre);
        putValue(Action.SMALL_ICON,icono);
        putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION,"Poner la lamina de color "+nombre);
        putValue("color_de_fondo",color_boton);



    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Color c=(Color)getValue("color_de_fondo");

        setBackground(c);

        System.out.println("Nombre: " + getValue(Action.NAME) + "\nDescripcion: " + getValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION));

      }


    }

}
```